# ¿Por qué sólo me funciona una vez la comunicación? AJAX, JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor. -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CALCULOS</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){            
            $("#enviaruno").on("click", function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    url:"NewServlet",//servlet destino 
                    dataType: "html", //tipo de respuesta que se recibe del servidor
                    data: "control=EJERCICIO1"
                            +"&numeroPar="+$("#numeroPar").val(),
                    method:"POST",//GET
                    success: function(respuesta){                        
                        if(respuesta){ 
                            $("#resultado1").val(respuesta);
                        }else{
                           alert("Error al procesar su peticion");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(objAjax, estado, excepcion){
                        alert("error en la comunicación");
                    }
                });    
            });
            $("#enviardos").on("click", function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    url:"NewServlet",//servlet destino 
                    dataType: "html", //tipo de respuesta que se recibe del servidor
                    data: "control=EJERCICIO2"
                            +"&priProducto="+$("#priProducto").val()
                            +"&segProducto="+$("#segProducto").val(),         
                    method:"POST",//GET
                    success: function(respuesta){                        
                        if(respuesta){ 
                            $("#resultado2").val(respuesta);
                        }else{
                           alert("Error al procesar su peticion");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(objAjax, estado, excepcion){
                        alert("error en la comunicación");
                    }
                });     
            });
            $("#enviartres").on("click",function(){
               $.ajax({
                url:"NewServlet",
                dataType:"html",
                data:"control=EJERCICIO3"
                        +"&priMayor="+$("#priMayor").val()
                        +"&segMayor="+$("#segMayor").val(),
                method:"POST",
                success:function(respuesta){
                    if(respuesta){
                        $("#resultado3").val(respuesta);
                    }else{
                        alert("Error al procesar su peticion");
                    }
                },
                error:function(objAjax, estado, excepcion){
                    alert("Error al procesar su peticion");
                }
               });
            });
         });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>NUMERO PAR</h1>
        <form action="NewServlet" name="formulario">
            <p>
              Ingrese numero: <input type="text" id="numeroPar" name="numeroPar"><br>
              Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado1" name="resultado1"><br>
              <input type="button" id="enviaruno" value="calcular"> 
            </p>
        </form>
        <h1>PRODUCTO DE NUMEROS</h1>
        <form action="NewServlet" name="formulario">
            <P>
                Ingrese primer numero: <input type="text" id="priProducto" name="priProducto"><br>
                Ingrese segundo numero: <input type="text" id="segProducto" name="segProducto"><br>
                Resultado:  <input type="text" id="resultado2"  name="resultado2"><br>
                <input type="button" id="enviardos" value="calcular">
            </P>            
        </form>

         <form action="NewServlet" name="formulario">
            <h1>NUMERO MAYOR ENTRE DOS DATOS NUMERICOS </h1>
            <p>
            Ingrese primer número: <input type="text" id="priMayor" name="priMayor"><br>
            Ingrese segundo número: <input type="text" id="segMayor" name="segMayor"><br>
            Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado3" name="resultado3"><br>
            <input type="button" id="enviartres" value="calcular">
            </p>
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

---

**Mi servlet**

```
package Control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import Modelos.Calculadora;
/**
 *
 * @author XXXXX
 */
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        Calculadora calcular=new Calculadora();
        String numeroPar= request.getParameter("numeroPar");
        String control=request.getParameter("control");
        float priProducto=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("priProducto"));
        float segProducto=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("segProducto"));
        float priMayor=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("priMayor"));
        float segMayor=Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("segMayor"));
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            if(control.equals("EJERCICIO1"))
            {           
             out.println(calcular.parOImpar(numeroPar)); 
            }
            if(control.equals("EJERCICIO2")){
                out.println(calcular.producto(priProducto, segProducto));
            } 
            if(control.equals("EJERCICIO3")){
                out.println(calcular.numeroMayor(priMayor, segMayor));
            } 
        }
    }


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**Clase `Calculadora`**

```
package Modelos;
public class Calculadora {
    public void Calculadora(){

    }
    float mayor;
    String par;
    public String parOImpar(String a)
    {
        float numero=Float.parseFloat(a);
        if((numero%2)==0)
        {
            par="ES PAR";

        }else
        {
            par= "ES IMPAR";
        }
            return par;
    }
    public float numeroMayor(float a, float b)
    {   
        mayor=0;
        if((a>b) ||(a==b))
        {
           mayor= a;
        } else
        {
          mayor=b;
        }  
     return mayor;
    }
```

Comment: ¿En la consola de depuración de javascript de tu navegador aparece algún error? Cuando alguna función javascript se ejecuta una única vez suele estar provocado por un error de javascript que detiene su funcionamiento. ¿En el inspector de red ves más de una petición o sólo la primera? ¿Podrías describir mejor qué problema tienes, cómo reproducirlo y el resultado esperado?

Comment: @OscarGarcia soy nuevo en este sitio (tuve que editar el contenido varias veces), pues me funciona/responde de buena manera en el primer ejercicio, luego en los restantes me tira "error al procesar su petición" o sea: else{
                           alert("Error al procesar su peticion");

Comment: Revisa que vale respuesta en la vuelta de las peticiones.

Comment: ¿En el inspector de red puedes ver el tipo de respuesta HTTP y su contenido?¿En el lado de java (imagino que usarás tomcat, weblogic, geronimo, wildfly, etc) ves excepciones o mensajes de error? Es probable que necesitemos ver la implementación de la clase `Calculadora` para ver si es allí donde está el problema. También debes tener en cuenta que puedes recibir un `NumberFormatException` al hacer el `Float.parseFloat()` si lo que se recibe no es un número de coma flotante correcto, y eso no lo estás controlando. Prueba a mover el `try` más arriba.

Comment: pues en la consola no me tira error o alguna advertencia

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya subi mi clase Calculadora para que observen

Comment: Vale, descartado que sea de la clase `Calculadora`, así que sólo resta una explicación. Redactando.

Comment: me cambie a chrome y en este me resuelve dos ejercicios y uno no, en este si me tira error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).   ahora lo he vuelto a ejecutar y ahora resulta que no me ejecuta ninguno: "error en la comunicacion".

Comment: El código HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) es debido a una excepción que no has capturado en el servidor java. Mira mi respuesta y procura blindar todo el código para hacer frente a cualquier eventualidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no estás capturando el caso en el que [`Float.parseFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) provoque una excepción `NumberFormatException` debido a que reciba un parámetro que no pueda ser convertido a coma flotante o `NullPointerException` si recibe un `null` porque [`ServletRequest.getParameter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) no encontró el campo GET solicitado.

Así que hay que gestionar esos casos como en el siguiente ejemplo propuesto:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Calculadora calcular = new Calculadora();
    /* En general capturamos todo el bloque que haga uso de out */
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* Primero obtenemos el control, lo que debemos hacer */
        String control = request.getParameter("control");
        if (control == null) {
            out.println("No sé qué hacer, defina 'control'");
            return;
        }
        /* Si estamos con par/impar hacemos el trabajo */
        if (control.equals("EJERCICIO1")) {
            String numeroPar = request.getParameter("numeroPar");
            if (numeroPar == null) {
                out.println("Introduzca el parámetro 'numeroPar'");
            } else {
                out.println(calcular.parOImpar(numeroPar));
            }
        } else if (control.equals("EJERCICIO2")) {
            /* Capturamos todos los posibles errores de conversión */
            try {
                float priProducto = Float.parseFloat(
                    request.getParameter("priProducto")
                );
                float segProducto = Float.parseFloat(
                    request.getParameter("segProducto")
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            out.println(calcular.producto(priProducto, segProducto));
        } else if (control.equals("EJERCICIO3")) {
            /* Capturamos todos los posibles errores de conversión */
            try {
                float priMayor = Float.parseFloat(
                    request.getParameter("priMayor")
                );
                float segMayor = Float.parseFloat(
                    request.getParameter("segMayor")
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            out.println(calcular.numeroMayor(priMayor, segMayor));
        } 
    }
}
```

En cuanto a la clase `Calculadora`:

```
package Modelos;
public class Calculadora {
    float mayor;
    String par;
    public void Calculadora() {
    }
    public String parOImpar(String a)
    {
        try {
            float numero = Float.parseFloat(a);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error en la conversión del parámetro";
        }
        if ((numero % 2) == 0) {
            return "ES PAR";
        } else {
            return "ES IMPAR";
        }
    }
    public float numeroMayor(float a, float b)
    {
        if (a >= b) {
           return a;
        } else {
           return b;
        }
    }
```

Por último, en jQuery no es necesario que montes las cadenas GET, lo hace por ti si lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#enviaruno").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "NewServlet",//servlet destino
        dataType: "html", //tipo de respuesta que se recibe del servidor
        data: {
            "control": "EJERCICIO1",
            "numeroPar": $("#numeroPar").val(),
        },
        method:"POST",//GET
        success: function(respuesta) {
            if (respuesta) {
                $("#resultado1").val(respuesta);
            } else {
                alert("Error al procesar su peticion");
            }
        },
        error: function(objAjax, estado, excepcion) {
            alert("error en la comunicación");
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a ir editarlo y luego regreso para comentarte que tal me fue

Comment: He vuelto, me ha ido de maravilla, que bueno que exista gente como tú, de corazón mil gracias.

Comment: De nada, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si solucionó tu problema :)

Comment: Me alegro de haber sido de ayuda ;)

Comment: Esta bien pero como tengo menos de 15 de reputación no cambia aunque la marque como correcta, gracias.

Comment: No te preocupes, terminará por marcarse.

Comment: Hola, ¿Has redactado una nueva pregunta explicando este problema?